# No data is showing connectedcallback() method

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am creating a data table based upon the return from the apex. I am calling this component from another component and passing the recordid.

**Component 1:**

```
<c-compoennt2 con-id={recordId}>
```

**Component 2:**

```
import apexmethd ....;
@api conId

connectedCallback(){
this.getAllCaseDetails();
}

getAllCaseDetails(){
getAccountList({ContactId:'$conId'})
.then(data => {
//populating result here
```

I am not getting any data in component1 UI. How can I resolve this?

Comment: @Rahul, can you pls check my comments below.

Comment: You have written that in the answer section not comments, please edit the above question.

Answer (score 0):

The `'$propertyName'` format works only with wired properties or functions, not the imperative apex calls. Use `this.propertyName` format like below

```
getAccountList({ContactId: this.conId})
```

Also please log that value before passing to the apex call and make sure that the values are coming from the parent.